# php include file autocompletion path uploaded on server differs

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, include-path, php-include

```
root/
  controller/
    controller.php
  view/
    view.php
  index.php
```

I launch the index.php, it includes controller.php and from controller.php I want to include view.php.
**What's the best way to do it?**

The problem is NetBeans autocomplete wants me to format the path like this:

> include '../view/view.php';

But on the server, when index.php is launched, it says:

> Failed opening '../view/view.php' for inclusion (include_path='.') in /mnt/.../controller/controller.php

Possible solutions:

1. Now, I write inclusion from index.php *include 'view/view.php';* manually (but I **can't use autocomplete**)
2. I might put *chdir(__ DIR __);* before the inclusion and stole the current directory (I think it's stupid to write it before every inclusion)
3. I might use project.properties hack from https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219236#c6 (not clean)

I think every PHP programmer has to deal with this but surprisingly, the web is silent.
Note that any form of *include ROOT.'view/view.php'* is not understood by autocompletion https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=186971

Thanks!

Comment: change `include '../view/view.php';` to `include dirname(__FILE__).'/../view/view.php';`

Comment: As I stated in the end of the question, this syntax is not supported by autocompletion. There is an enhancement request for this since 2010 but with very low priority.